# How to run weblogic managed server as windows service for 14c Weblogic version

Tags: windows, service, weblogic

How to run WebLogic managed server as windows service for 14c Weblogic version
Currently I am using following bat file to start the application manually.

```bat
ECHO OFF

ECHO "Managed server will start in 30 seconds"

start D:\bea14\user_projects\domains\basedomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 30 > nul

start D:\bea14\user_projects\domains\basedomain\bin\startManagedWebLogic.cmd mangedservername http://localhost:7003
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing a good atrating point could be the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/standalone/weblogic-server/14.1.1.0/start/winservice.html#GUID-6A5A23B2-2EAB-4C3E-8711-B7BA49C50D75) about running servers in service mode.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link.